# Change the font of an Mvx.MvxGridView?

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, font-awesome

I'm trying to use FontAwesome with Xamarin.Android and MvvmCross.  I have a Mvx.MvxGridView that data binds to an item source that returns the unicode value for FontAwesome.  The Mvx.MvxGridView uses an item template (local:MvxItemTemplate) for the template of each grid block.  How can I change the Mvx.MvxGridView or MvxItemTemplate font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the font in your adapter. It will look something like this.

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
{
            var item = _menuItems[position];
            var holder = viewHolder as MenuItemAdapterViewHolder;
            holder.icon.SetTypeFace(Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Application.Context.Assets, "<Insert file path here>"), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            holder.icon.Text = item.IconFont;
}
```